# Missing Space after Year in apa-Style for biblatex in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style

I'm currently working on a beamer presentation and I'm using the biblatex package with the apa style for citations. I noticed that when I use \printbibliography, there is no space between the year and the title.

Instead of:

> De Winter, J. C., & Dodou, D. (2015). A surge of p-values between 0.041 and 0.049 in
> recent decades (but negative results are increasing rapidly too). PeerJ, 3,
> e733

The current settings print the following entry:

> De Winter, J. C., & Dodou, D. (2015).A surge of p-values between 0.041 and 0.049 in
> recent decades (but negative results are increasing rapidly too). PeerJ, 3,
> e733

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{dewinter2015surge,
  title={A surge of p-values between 0.041 and 0.049 in recent decades (but negative results are increasing rapidly too)},
  author={De Winter, Joost CF and Dodou, Dimitra},
  journal={PeerJ},
  volume={3},
  pages={e733},
  year={2015},
  publisher={PeerJ Inc.}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textcite{dewinter2015surge} presented a new approach to the classification of abstracts
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{References}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I've seen this problem recently. Let me look if I can find the post.

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/212#issuecomment-1611907367

Comment: @moewe Would you like to post an answer?

Comment: @ CapsLock BTW: very nice first post! It is rare to see ones with a nice reproducible example!

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked directly. (:

Comment: @ CapsLock You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

This problem is discussed in https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/212 and will be resolved in a future version of `biblatex-apa`.

It is caused by an unfortunate combination of punctuation macros in `biblatex-apa` and `beamer`'s trying to patch `biblatex` macros to insert its colours.

For most intents and purposes the fix in `biblatex-apa` should resolve the issue. If you need it now, you can rewrite the driver with `\printunit`. But remember to remove this monstrosity from your preamble once `biblatex-apa` is updated.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[
  style = apa,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor}%
  \printunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{apa:related}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{howpublished}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+url}%
  \newblock
  \usebibmacro{origyear}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{annotation}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, E., & Ryde, U. (1998). Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19(4), 377–395.]